# Null checking with primary constructor in C# 12

Tags: c#, .net-8.0, fail-fast, c#-12.0, primary-constructor

I using C# 12.
In C# 12 I can use primary constructor:

```
public class UserService(IUnitOfWork uow) : IUserService
{
}
```

Before C# 12 I used null checking for items that I inject in constructor:

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public UserService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(uow);
        _uow = uow;
    }
}
```

Now how can I do null checking in C# 12 ?
Is it need to use fail fast with primary constructor ?

Comment: That's null checking, not `fail fast`. The primary constructor *doesn't* define a field, it defines a parameter that's in scope for the entire class. You can still use null checking in the field assignment.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: In this case, it's both: OP wants the code to crash early, when UserService is initialized, rather than late, when `uow` is accessed.

Comment: Be aware that if you use a primary constructor, the field that it introduces is NOT READONLY. Which is quite annoying. See [Nick Chapsas's video about it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IABO8O9cZOw)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Indeed. Fortunately, the C# team thinks the same and has announced that they want to fix this in the next version (probably with an optional `readonly` modifier for PC parameters).

Comment: Wait what? You're passing a _unit of work_ to the constructor of a _service_?? That doens't seem right. Even passing the database _context_ is not a great idea, as I will block the database. But a unit of work should be _severly_ limited in lifetime.

Comment: can't you use `!!` ?

Comment: @RandRandom: That feature was only available during preview of C#11 and [has been removed](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/#remove-parameter-null-checking-from-c-11).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I know if you want to switch to primary constructors one of the easiest options would be to introduce field/property:

```
public class UserService(IUnitOfWork uow) : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow = uow 
         ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uow));
}
```

Note that you can also name the field the same as your constructor parameter (`_uow` -> `uow`), if you don't want to clutter your class with an extra name (as suggested by [Heinzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87698/heinzi)) which has additional benefit of shadowing the mutable primary ctor parameter by an immutable field.

You can also encapsulate the logic into helper method. Something along these lines:

```
public class UserService(IUnitOfWork uow) : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork uow = uow.IsNotNull();
}

public static class Check
{
    [return:NotNull]
    public static T IsNotNull<T>(this T t,
         [CallerArgumentExpression("t")] string? paramName = null) where T : class
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(t, paramName);
        return t;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't use the helper method, `private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow = uow ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(uow));` is a bit shorter. You can also name the field the same as your constructor parameter (`_uow` -> `uow`), if you don't want to clutter your class with an additional name: Yes, `private ... uow = uow.IsNotNull();` looks strange, but it works.

Comment: Naming the field and the PC parameter the same has the additional advantage that your *mutable* PC parameter is now shadowed by an *immutable* field.

Comment: Thank you @Heinzi , updated! As for the field name - followed the convention from OP. Added as a remark to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Opinionated: for this example I would omit the null check.  It adds code (a liability), at the expense of clutter and distraction.  I don't see the value because if `uow` is null things will blow up quickly in `UserService` tests, the cause will be obvious, and be solved (probably) by registering IUnitOfWork.

Comment: agreed. If you can't trust your dependency injection, then you'll have a big problem anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You can define properties with private setters and perform null checks in these setters.

```cs
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public IUnitOfWork Uow
    {
        get => _uow;
        private set => _uow = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
    }

    public UserService(IUnitOfWork uow) => Uow = uow;

    // Other methods...
}
```

or you could use even try using Constructor Chaining so where the primary constructor calls a private constructor that performs the null checks.

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public UserService(IUnitOfWork uow) : this(uow, true) { }

    private UserService(IUnitOfWork uow, bool checkNull)
    {
        if (checkNull)
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(uow, nameof(uow));
        }

        _uow = uow;
    }

    // Other methods...
}
```